# Windows Phone 7 Panorama/Pivot DataBinding with static page

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7

I would like to have a panorama or pivot using Databinding (that works) but with one panoramaItem or PivotItem that is not Databinded.

The goal is to have a first page with top most topics and others pages showing all topics.

(I've tried to add a panorama into a pivotItem it works but the gesture conflicts (of course))

Have you an idea to achieve this ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rather than require to have some items data bound and others not, you could data bind to an ObservableCollection and manipulate the contents of that collection at runtime to achieve your presentation goals.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. It's already what I do: on the firstpage, I have a listbox databinded with some datas. This listbox is a part of a Panorama which I want to be binded another item list and have it to be as expended as there is lists to display. I can do each of these separatly whereas I want to Combine. And to make this more difficult, items for the listbox are not the same as for other panorama pages.